# Ubuntu 18.04 Ukrainian keyboard layout starts printing roman characters spontaneously

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, language-support, ibus, fcitx

When I switched from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 I noticed that keyboard layout takes a bit of time to switch (1-3 seconds) unlike Ubuntu 16.04 where that change was instant.
I decided to look for solutions on the internet and found solution to similar problem [here](https://whynhow.info/41301/Why-does-the-keyboard-layout-switch-long-in-Ubuntu-1204?). It didn't help so I installed gnome-tweaks and tried to check if there is something that may intentionally create delay but found none. I also found other solution which recommended to reinstall ibus, so I did. Then when nothing helped I just gave up on it. The next day I noticed that my Ukrainian keyboard layout behaves weirdly. When I switch to Ukrainian keyboard layout it prints cyrillic characters but then it spontaneously starts printing roman characters instead with Ukrainian language selected (I have Ukrainian and English (US) languages). I don't know which of the solutions I tried caused that. Is there some way to reset keyboard settings to default ones (ones that are set on OS installation) or it would be easier just to reinstall OS. Thank you in advance.

Edit: I managed to fix my issue. I used my browser history to find exact commands I typed. The problem was fcitx package I installed and I guess it conflicted with ibus. Once I removed it everything worked.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, did you try System Settings > Text Entry ? And confirm that the Language support is fully installed on the settings?

Comment: Let's figure out what your current input source settings look like. Please edit your question and show us the output of these two terminal commands: 1. `cat /etc/default/keyboard` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: I managed to solve my problem by purging fcitx package. Thanks for your replies anyway, I honestly was surprised that someone replied in such a shot time span.